# OpenSceneGraph-OpenSceneGraph-3.6.3/src/osgViewer/GraphicsWindowCocoa.mm: Objective-C++ compiler not installed on this system

Tags: android, openscenegraph

[ 57%] Building CXX object src/osgWrappers/serializers/osgParticle/CMakeFiles/osgdb_serializers_osgparticle.dir/LinearInterpolator.cpp.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object src/osgViewer/CMakeFiles/osgViewer.dir/GraphicsWindowCocoa.mm.o
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: /Users/shuxinghu/Downloads/OpenSceneGraph-OpenSceneGraph-3.6.3/src/osgViewer/GraphicsWindowCocoa.mm: Objective-C++ compiler not installed on this system
make[2]: *** [src/osgViewer/CMakeFiles/osgViewer.dir/GraphicsWindowCocoa.mm.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/osgViewer/CMakeFiles/osgViewer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 57%] Building CXX object src/osgWrappers/serializers/osgTerrain/CMakeFiles/osgdb_serializers_osgterrain.dir/HeightFieldLayer.cpp.o

Comment: [ 65%] Building CXX object src/osgWrappers/deprecated-dotosg/osg/CMakeFiles/osgdb_deprecated_osg.dir/Viewport.cpp.o
[ 65%] Linking CXX static library ../../../../lib/libosgdb_deprecated_osg.a
[ 65%] Built target osgdb_deprecated_osg
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Something is odd here. You seem to be building arm-linux-androidabi but are compiling .mm Objective C/C++ files (which are for iOS).

Which target are you building for and what is your build environment?

What did you configure in the CMake build settings?